# Aligning Header to bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align some text to the bottom of div in html/css and having quite a bit of difficulty. 
Everything I've read online indicates this is very simple, you just set the parent div to relative positioning, set the text to absolute positioning, and set the bottom value to 0px on the text itself. This hasn't worked for me so far. Also,  I'm trying to align the text to the bottom right. Aligning to the right works fine, but I can't get the text to move to the bottom.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class = "topContainer">
    <div class = "icon">
        <div class = "iconHeader">
                <h2>icon</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "topBar">
            <h1>top bar</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
h1 {
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 250%;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
h2 {
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 150%;
    color:black;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
/*Specific Page Elements*/
.topContainer {
    position: relative;
    float:center;
    height:100px;
    width:75%;
    margin: auto;
    padding:5px;
}
.icon {
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.iconHeader {
    background-color:white;
}
.topBar {
    background-color:black;
    float:right;
    width:77%;
    height:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong or have any suggestions?

Comment: What text do you want to set to the bottom? "Icon" or "top bar"?

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't specify that. Top bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple,just add the margin:0px

```
h1 {
font-family:Helvetica;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 250%;
color:white;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b0ec6jpn/

Comment: Or do what you should have done from the beginning: USE A CSS RESET ;)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is have your top bar have `position: relatve` and also add `margin-top: 55px;`and also add `text-align: right;`

Here is a link http://codepen.io/HTMLNoob/pen/WrJjwX

Comment: Each browser adds different browser specific css, 55px might work in chrome but won't in firefox. Use a css reset instead....